# @Resource outside the @Controller on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to access an @Resource from an pojo class, but i cant. I allways get NullPointer. Im using Spring Boot framework, 1.4.2.RELEASE version.

Is it possible? Here is part of my code:

```
    @Service
    public class CvFacade implements Cvitae{

        @Resource
        private CvRepository cvDao;

    //....
    }


   public interface CvRepository extends CrudRepository<Cv, Long>{

    @Query("select c from Cv c where c.idiom = :idiom")
    public List<Cv> listarCv(@Param("idiom") EnumIdiom idiom);


    @Query("select c from Person c where c.idPerson=1")
    public List<Person> listarPerson();


}
```

my Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.xxxxxx.cv.controller","com.xxxxxx.cv.facade","com.xxxxxx.cv.repository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxxxxx.cv.repository"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//...

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace that's generated?

Comment: it doesnt generate any stack trace. I just get null object.

Answer (score 0):

Your CvRepository interface should be annotated as a [Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html):

```
@Repository
public interface CvRepository extends CrudRepository<Cv, Long>{

    @Query("select c from Cv c where c.idiom = :idiom")
    public List<Cv> listarCv(@Param("idiom") EnumIdiom idiom);

    @Query("select c from Person c where c.idPerson=1")
    public List<Person> listarPerson();
}
```

This will expose CvRepository to the Spring context, making it available to inject into your CvFacade class.

Comment: Try put all objects in the same package

Comment: The Repository annotation is not necessary for Spring Data based repository interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do couple of configurations in your application,

1. Add @Repositry annotation on all your `Repository` components so that they are available for `component scan`.

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface CvRepository extends CrudRepository<Cv, Long>{

        @Query("select c from Cv c where c.idiom = :idiom")
        public List<Cv> listarCv(@Param("idiom") EnumIdiom idiom);

        @Query("select c from Person c where c.idPerson=1")
        public List<Person> listarPerson();
     }
   ```
2. You need to define your repository package to be scanned in `@EnableJpaRepositories` on your configuration class.

   ```
   e.g. @EnableJpaRepositories("your_package")
   ```

Comment: The Repository annotation is not necessary for Spring Data based repository interfaces

Comment: I already have: <code>@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxxxx.cv.repository","com.xxxxx.cv.facade"}, entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf") </code>

Answer (score 0):

In [standard Spring style](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.12.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods), you annotate a field, constructor or setter on the Service with @Autowired (or @Inject):

```
@Service
public class CvFacade implements Cvitae {

    private CvRepository cvDao;

    @Autowired
    public CvFacade(CvRepository cvDao) {
        this.cvDao = cvDao;
    }

    //....
}
```

That should then allow you to get access to it within the service. You do not need to place @Repository on the repository [if it already extends one of the Spring Data repository classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.12.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.definition).